# How do I access data in Firebase and visualize with D3.js?

Tags: d3.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my data stored as JSON in Firebase.  I want to use D3.js to create a visualization from that data.  My previous experience in D3 has always been to load in specific files:

```
d3.csv ('csv-file-here.csv', callbackfunction);
```

OR

```
d3.json('json-file-here.json', callbackfunction);
```

But now that I need D3 to "access" or "pull" from Firebase, I'm a little bit lost as to how to do that.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

Okay, so I discovered this: https://github.com/mattdodge/D3Fire which can make Firebase and D3 talk to each other.  However, I tried following the instructions and still can't get anything to work. That "Hello World" and `console.log` statement does not print anything out.

```
d3.select('svg').firebase(
    'https://mydatabaseURL.com',
    {
        createFunc : function(newData) {
            // callback when data is added
            console.log(newData.val());
            d3.select("body").append("span").text("Hello, world!");
            return this.append('text').text(newData.val());
        },
        updateFunc : function(changedData) {
            // data was changed, let's change the text
            this.text(changedData.val());
        }
    }
);
```

**Edit 2:**

If I did it without the above plugin, nothing is printed out either...

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref();

ref.on('value', function(dataSnapshot){
   console.log(dataSnapshot.val());
});
```

**Edit 3:**

My issue was in my database security rules.  I reverted that back to default and now I am able to establish a connection with Firebase and get the snapshot to print out my database as an object array.  Now, I need to figure out how to actually load that data into D3.  I tried `d3.json(dataSnapshot.val(), function(rawdata){})` but that didn't load it in.

**Edit 4:**

Okay, the D3 docs seem to indicate that `d3.json()` takes a URL for the location where the request for the JSON can be made.  So, if it is in a local folder, `data.json` will suffice.  Because I want to get it from Firebase, I need to find out a way to load in that Firebase as a JSON.  So I tried

```
d3.json('https://mydatabasename.firebaseio.com/.json', update);
```

which still did not work.  Printing out the raw data gives me `undefined`.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console? What version of Firebase are you using? You second edit suggests it's version 3. Have you [initialized Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app)? Also, D3Fire has not been updated for a long time, so it won't work with the latest Firebase API.

Comment: @cartant Yes, I have initialized Firebase as I have email/password authentication working as well.  Yes, Firebase version 3 and no, no errors in the console.  If D3Fire does not work, then for my "Edit 2," I put `console.log` statements everywhere and it seems to run the `ref.on` statement but doesn't print anything out.

Answer (score 0):

Make a reference to your firebase. Wait for it to load data. Then draw your d3 visualization.

```js
var ref = firebase.database().ref();

ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {

  var data = snapshot.val();
  // draw your d3 vis here using the data

});
```

Comment: I tried that but instead just tried doing a `console.log` instead that callback function but nothing is ever printed out...

Comment: There is still not really enough information in your question. It seems that you might be struggling to make a connection to a Firebase ref, and d3 isn't yet part of your problem. But without seeing how you are attempting to make that connection, I could only speculate as to what the problem is.

Comment: Hm, my second edit is literally what I am doing in the code and I thought that is how to make a connection (to do: `ref.on('value', function())`)

Comment: Update: okay, I figured out the error.  There was something going on in my database security rules that was causing problems.  Now, I confirm that the `snapshot.val())` prints the full object array which is in my database.  Hurray!